# Traerme todos los documentos de una colección es lo mismo que traer uno por uno (En cuanto eficiencia)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Me estoy trayendo una colección llena de productos (nombre, unidad, precio, creadoEn, proveedor) (No son muy largos los documentos pero son muchos), pero el problema que tengo actualmente es que tiene que pasar como 15 segundos hasta que se traiga toda la coleccion. Mi duda es si me traigo documento por documento va a ser mas eficiente o no?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy costoso leer todos los documentos todas las veces que vas a ir a esa colección, imaginate que esa coleccion tiene 100.000 documentos, vas a estar pasandote del plan gratis el doble por solo 1 lectura a esa coleccion y los costos al pasarte a un plan pago por uso serian muy elevados.

Lo que te recomiendo es que uses querys, ya que Firestore te da la posibilidad de tener querys compuestas, podes crear querys que te traigan solo lo que necesitas, de esta forma no vas a traer todos los documentos de la coleccion sino los que te hagan falta

Otra forma de evitar esa carga de 15 segundos (que de por si es bastante) es paginar tus resultados, por ejemplo, cargar los primeros 15 productos mostrarle al usuario (15 lecturas) despues si el usuario llega al final de la lista cargar otros 15 (30 lecturas) y asi vas cargando a medida que el usuario va deslizando la lista, de esta forma te ahorras muchisimo tiempo de carga y evitas muchisimas lecturas innecesarias que quizas el usuario nunca alcance a leer.